# Python converting encoded string to utf8?

Tags: python, encoding

I have a text file which I cannot be certain of the encoding type. The text file is then opened using python open function and monitored for any new content.

This is the program:

```
import time
import os
import sys
from threading import Timer
from base_logger import logger
from service_check import service_info, machine_name

def follow(thefile):
    '''generator function that yields new lines in a file
    '''
    # seek the end of the file
    thefile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    
    # start infinite loop
    while True:
        # read last line of file
        line = thefile.readline()
        # sleep if file hasn't been updated
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue

        yield line

def detectLicenseStopping(line):
    stopStr = "Stopping license"

    if stopStr in line:
        logger.info("Detected: " +  str(line) + " " + str(type(line)))


def main(argv):
    logfile = open(argv[0], mode="r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    # iterate over the generator
    for line in loglines:
        detectLicenseStopping(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The variable line is a line read from the text file. I am trying to detect if the stopStr variable is inside this line variable. However, the detection would fail as the line and stopStr looks visibly different :(

This is the value of the line during debugging:

```
'\x002\x005\x00/\x001\x000\x00/\x002\x001\x00 \x002\x002\x00:\x000\x000\x00:\x005\x006\x00 \x00(\x001\x000\x004\x004\x00)\x00 \x00S\x00t\x00o\x00p\x00p\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00l\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00n\x00s\x00e\x00 \x00F\x00C\x00T\x00C\x001\x002\x000\x001\x000\x000\x000\x004\x002\x007\x000\x004\x005\x005\x007\x009\x003\x009\x005\x007\x00 \x00o\x00n\x00 \x00W\x001\x002\x006\x00P\x00A\x00A\x00P\x001\x00.\x00'
```

How should I convert the line into its appropriate string (utf-8) representation? I tried using the str function but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.  Are we to manually type in the strings to test them?  Post text  and format as code blocks.  Plus we can't see much of the string, but it looks like UTF-16BE.  Use `open(file,encoding='utf-16be')` to read it.

Comment: *"a text file which I do not know its encoding type"* — Start here and figure out what encoding its in, then read it appropriately.

Comment: Read [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html), and [What every programmer should know about Unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) library to detect the encoding.

```
line_encoding = chardet.detect(line)["encoding"]
utf8_string = line.decode(line_encoding)
```